# how to represent a property to a property in RDF

Tags: rdf

Say I have a triple of `user, action type, object` like so:

```
andy visited url1
andy visited url2
```

How would I encode a timestamp value to these relations so we know `andy` visited `url1` before `url2`?

Is RDF even the right data model to use or should I be using a property graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could model it by making the visit it's own Resource to which you can attach data:

```
:Andy :visited [ 
  :url <the_visited_url>; 
  :timestamp "the timestamp"^^xsd:dateTime 
].
```

Or:

```
:Visit1 a :Visit; 
  :visitedBy :Andy; 
  :url <the_visited_url>; 
  :timestamp "the timestamp"^^xsd:dateTime.
```

In either case, the visit itself is a concept, which lets you say whatever you want about it, including when it happened or what URL was visited.